# Losing part of data of Property in Component Angular(typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb

So i have a component in angular that receives data from a service (PageDataService)
puts the data in receivedData and later calls this data when using the sentData function
but when i look at the data inside it appears the it looses some of the data.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PageDataService } from 'src/app/core/services/page-data.service';
import { iTempDish, iTempOrder } from '../../models/order.model';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { DatabaseReferencesService } from 'src/app/core/services/database-references.service';
import { iRecipe } from 'src/app/core/models/recipe.model';
import { iIngredient } from 'src/app/core/models/ingredient.model';
import { iCategory } from 'src/app/core/models/category.model';
import { eDishModificationType, eDishStatus } from 'src/app/core/models/dish.model';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { NotifierComponent } from 'src/app/core/components/notifier/notifier.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class MenuSelectorComponent {

  receivedData: iTempOrder | undefined;  //in this i put data during ngInit

  tables: string[] = [];  //temp values for debug
  room: string = "";

  categoryReference: iCategory[] | undefined;
  subscriptionCategory: Subscription | undefined;
  ingredientReference: iIngredient[] | undefined;
  subscriptionIngredient: Subscription | undefined;
  recipeReference: iRecipe[] | undefined;
  subscriptionRecipe: Subscription | undefined;

  displayedRecipe: iRecipe[] | undefined;

  tempDishes: iTempDish[] = [];

  modificationsArray = ['add', 'remove', 'more', 'less'];


  constructor(private pagedata: PageDataService, private dataReference: DatabaseReferencesService, private notifier: NotifierComponent, private router: Router) {
...
//initializing data and subscription (unrelated to the received data)
}

ngOnInit(): void{
  this.receivedData = this.pagedata.data;
    this.tables = this.receivedData!.order!.tables;
    this.room = this.receivedData!.order!.room;
    console.log("ngInit", this.receivedData);
}
//those six function are unrelated and work on "tempDishes" and dont touch the reveiced data in any way
ngOnDestroy(): void {... //unsubscribe}
addCourse(recipeAdded: iRecipe){}
onAddNote(index: number){}
onAddIngredient(index: number){}
removeIngredient(dish: number, element:number){}
remove course(index:number){}


sentData(){

    //send data to the pagedata service
    console.log("SendData ", this.receivedData);
    console.log("tables", this.tables);
    console.log("room", this.room);
    this.receivedData!.courses!.push({
      dishes: this.tempDishes,
    });
    this.receivedData!.order!.tables = this.tables;
    this.receivedData!.order!.room = this.room;
    console.log("afterAsign", this.receivedData);
    this.pagedata.data = this.receivedData;
    this.router.navigate(['/core/waiter/orders/detail']);
    }
   }
```

here is the photo of the logs that i get
[image]

so as you can see somehow i get the data in the temporal variables tables and room
but inside the object received data it says undefined

here is the interface of the received data:

itempOrder:

```js
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { eDishModificationType, eDishStatus } from "src/app/core/models/dish.model";
import { iIngredient } from "src/app/core/models/ingredient.model";
import { eOrderStatus, iOrder } from "src/app/core/models/order.model";
import { iRecipe } from "src/app/core/models/recipe.model";
import { iRoom } from "src/app/core/models/room.model";
import { iTable } from "src/app/core/models/table.model";

export interface iOrderData {
    room: string;
    tables: string;
    guests: string;
    status: eOrderStatus;
}

//----------------------------------------------
// Section: used in creating new courses for an order
export interface iTempDishModification {
    ingredient: iIngredient['_id'];
    name:       string;
    type:       eDishModificationType;
    price_modification?:       number;
}
export interface iTempDish {

    //temporary data used in frontend
    name?: string; //recipe.name
    description?: string; //recipe.description
    ingredients?: string[]; //recipe.ingredients

    //temporary forms used to insert data (notes) and add dish modifications
    formNotes?: FormGroup;
    formIngredients?: FormGroup;

    //-------------------------


    recipe: iRecipe['_id'];
    actual_price: number; //calculate in fromtend (recipe.price + if(modification) {ingredients.price} )
    notes?: string;
    status?: eDishStatus; //default: waiting by waiter
    modifications?: iTempDishModification[];

}
export interface iTempCourse {
    dishes: iTempDish[];
}
//----------------------------------------------


export interface iTempOrder {
    order: iOrder;
    courses?: iTempCourse[];
}
```

here is the iOrder

```js
import { iDish } from './dish.model';
import { iRoom } from './room.model';
import { iTable } from './table.model';
import { iUserAction } from './user_action.object';

export enum eOrderStatus {
    waiting = 'waiting',
    ordering = 'ordering',
    serving = 'serving',
    delivered = 'delivered',
}
export interface iLogCourse {
    created_course: iUserAction;
    served_course?: iUserAction;
    //future feature (not implemented)
    deleted_course?: iUserAction;
}
export interface iLogOrder {
    created_order: iUserAction;
    //not used
    //taken_order?: iUserAction;
}

export interface iCourse {
    _id?: string;
    dishes?: iDish['_id'][];
    logs_course?: iLogCourse;
}
export interface iOrder {
    _id?: string;
    guests: number;
    capacity: number;

    status?: eOrderStatus;
    room: iRoom['_id'];
    tables: iTable['_id'][];

    logs_order?: iLogOrder;
    courses: iCourse[];
    tempCourses?: iCourse[];


    final_price?: number;
}
```

and the iRoom and iTable are somewhat similar(contain _id and other info)

as you can see in console logs the data that im missing is the tables and rooms and i have no idea why, because when im assigning data there i put the strings table=['3']
room='1'
but somehow the object itself losses that data out of nowhere

i also tried to substitute the type in the interface with just string and string[]
but still got the same resault losing the data and i dont know why

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Don't trust the logs. console.* methods invoked on objects will usually lazily evaluate them (at least in chrome). This means that what you see can in your console.log output can be a state that is changed later than the console.log appeared. Set up the breakpoints in proper places in your code then investigate the issue further.